# PNG shadow with fluid height

Tags: css, png, shadow, pseudo-element

Due to browser performance implications I can't use `box-shadow` CSS property because I have many similarly looking elements on my page that should have same looking style including shadow. That's the reason I would like to implement shadows using traditional PNG imagery.

### Facts

1. My elements have predefined and more importantly **fixed** pixel width
2. They have fluid height (`auto`) depending on their content
3. They have content directly in the element and some child elements will be positioned outside their border
4. CSS3 can be used but performance-critical parts (gradients, shadows...) should be avoided
5. CSS pseudo elements can be used without limitation

### Requirements

1. There should be no additional wrapper element added in order to have fluid shadow
2. Application should run smoothly on mobile browsers - shadows seem to slow down performance significantly on mobile devices since their processing power is much lower than desktop computers.

### Possible direction

I thought of using `:before` and `:after` pseudos to display top-to-bottom and bottom shadows on the containing element, but these pseudos display within their parent element and positioning parent `z-index` higher than these children has no effect.

### Visual demo of end result

This [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kZGzn/1/) in pure CSS3 that I would like to achieve but using PNG shadows. In reality there are numerous of these boxes so you can imagine mobile browsers are struggling with all these shadows.

*Item* is one such box (see blow) that needs PNG shadow. Left menu is child element positioned outside of the box.

#### Display in Chrome

[image: CSS3 shadow]

#### HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <menu>
        <li><a href="#">Yes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">No</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Maybe</a></li>
    </menu>
    <div class="content">
        Some content
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS3 LESS

```
.item {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px calc(20px + 3.5em);
    min-height: 5em;

    &:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    &:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 10px;
        height: 5em;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: -3.5em;
        width: 3.5em;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;

        li a {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 2px 0;
        }
    }

    .content {
        padding: .75em 1em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I am missing something, but looks like you want something in this way:

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rye2d/)

The CSS is

```
.base {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    position: relative;
    z-index: auto;
}

.base:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 50px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    color: red;
}
```

And just change the background of the :after to your image.

I have applied this solution to your fiddle.

The relevant CSS is for the before pseudo element:

```
.item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/100/100);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

I have used a kitten picture, that is being scaled to cover all the needed size. Just change that to whatever you want.

I needed to do it that way because I had onky a pseudo element available.

The key for that to work (and where you probably had the difficulty) is to add z-index: auto to .item

## [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kZGzn/3/)

Well, I had said that it wasn't posible, but I have find a way.

The standard technique would be to use 2 elements, just to avoid stretching the image (as you said). The problem is that we only have 1 pseudo element available.

The solution then would be to use 1 pseudo element, but with 2 backgrounds, to solve the issue.

CSS (only relevant part)

```
.item:before {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/320/10), url(http://placekitten.com/320/500);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 9px, 100% calc(100% - 9px);
    background-position: left bottom, left top;
}
```

We will need an image (the first one) only 10 px in height, to cover the bottom shadow. And another one, with enough height to cover the maximumitem posible, and that will be used for the remaining part of the shadow. The dark part is that we need now a calc() height, with limited support. (anyway, better than border image)

## [demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/kZGzn/5/)

Comment: But basically you've added a wrapper (namely `base`) that's used. I want to avoid adding additional elements, as I may not have control of the HTML of these elements.

Comment: Not really, base is the element where the shadow is applied. And I put a child element to reproduce fact 3 of your question, but it isn't needed at all

Comment: I've updated my question to give you some visual clue about my end result.

Comment: That's better but since you haven't used an image of some shadow you probably already know this is not viable because you're vertically scaling background. This means that left and right shadow will be fine (mostly), but top and bottom will change dramatically with differently sized items.

Comment: Yes, I commented this issue in the answer. The problem is that to do that better, you will need 2 pseudo elements, and you are already using one in your original design.

Comment: This is actually not the best possible solution, but it definitely gave me a possibility. The only information that was so valuable I accepted your answer was the `z-index: -1`. I didn't even know you could set it to negative values. [And that has resolved](http://jsfiddle.net/d4s6K/) my issue as I wasn't able to put the element in front of its pseudo elements. The other (and likely best possible option) is using `border-image` property that's supported by all modern browsers except IE. But IE11 will support it (and I can see in Windows Blue that it really does.

Comment: I have find a better solution. Added fiddle, with traslucent background so that it can be seen that the image is not stretched. (you will need 2 images !)

Comment: Now this deserves a +1 as well. Even though I already accepted your answer as the correct one you invested a bit more time to provide a great possible solution one rarely thinks of...